# Link pug drop down list to a template

Tags: node.js, pug

Is there the way to use pug form dropdown list as a link to another pug template using node? I researched and found this:

```
.form-group
    label  
    select(name='region' placeholder="region" id="reg")
     option(value='/volta') v
     option(value='/accra') a
     option(value='/eastern') e
     option(value='/oti') o
     option(value='/savanna') s
     script.
      var urlmenu = document.getElementById( 'reg' )
      urlmenu.onchange = function() {
       window.open( this.options[ this.selectedIndex ].value )
```

Where /volta etc are the templates. This does not seem to work

Comment: AFAIK, `pug` templates are not http endpoints or routes so you cannot link to them. Pug files are rendered server-side so to navigate, you must have a route which renders a pug file and point to those routes.

Comment: thanks but what I really meant is how to make a drop down list with links to other templates with their routes created already.I hope you get what I am saying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a bit of syntax issues here I am guessing, fixing which makes your code work.

```
select(name='region' placeholder="region" id="reg")
  option(value='/volta') v
  option(value='/accra') a
  option(value='/eastern') e
  option(value='/oti') o
  option(value='/savanna') s
script.
  var urlmenu = document.getElementById('reg');
  urlmenu.onchange = function() { 
    window.open( this.options[ this.selectedIndex ].value )
    //or
    //window.location.href = this.options[ this.selectedIndex ].value
  }
```